# AWS EC2 - Node.js not working after reboot

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, nvm

I have set a small and free AWS instance up with an Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03.0 AMI. I created and configured two additional users (me and botManager) and nothing more. I then switched from ec2-user to botManager with `su botManager` and did not forgot to `cd ~`.

I installed node.js through nvm. To install nvm I simply copy/pasted this :

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.32.0/install.sh | bash
```

Made nvm accessible right away with :

```
. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
```

As explained here : [Tutorial: Setting Up Node.js on an Amazon EC2 Instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-up-node-on-ec2-instance.html)

Still no issue, not even a warning, `nvm --version` works and returns `0.32.0`.

I wanted the last LTS version so I ran :

```
nvm install --lts
```

And it went smoothly. Both `node -v` and `npm -v` worked and respectively returned `v8.11.3` and `5.6.0`.

To be sure that everything is stable I `ctrl+d` to log out from botManager and as ec2-user reboot the server with `sudo reboot`.

The problem is when I log back in as botManager after the reboot and change to its home directory (~) nvm is still working but `node -v` and `npm -v` return :

```
bash: (node or npm): command not found
```

Strangely, when I check with `nvm ls` which versions of node.js are installed I end up with this :

```
[botManager@ip-f-o-o-o ~]$ nvm ls
    v8.11.3
node -> stable (-> v8.11.3) (default)
stable -> 8.11 (-> v8.11.3) (default)
iojs -> N/A (default)
lts/* -> lts/argon (-> N/A)
lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.14.3 (-> N/A)
lts/carbon -> v8.11.3
```

How do I get node.js to work again and for long even after reboot ?

My Linux knowledge is very far from perfect and partly self-taught so any help is welcomed.

**Edit 1 :**
Results of `whereis node; echo path` :

```
[botManager@ip~]$ whereis node; echo $PATH node:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/aws/bin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin:/opt/aws/bin
```

**Edit 2 :**
New clean installation :
Results of `nvm install --lts` :

```
[botManager@ip-f-o-o-o~]$ nvm install --lts
Installing latest LTS version.
######################################################################## 100.0%
Computing checksum with sha256sum
Checksums matched!
Now using node v8.11.3 (npm v5.6.0)
nvm_ensure_default_set: a version is required
```

Results of `whereis node; echo path` :

```
[botManager@ip-f-o-o-o~]$ whereis node ; echo $PATH
node: /home/botManager/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/bin/node
```

`/home/botManager/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/aws/bin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin:/opt/aws/bin`

Results of `df -h` :

```
[botManager@ip-f-o-o-o~]$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        484M   56K  484M   1% /dev
tmpfs           494M     0  494M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvda1      7.8G  1.2G  6.6G  15% /
```

After a reboot :
  Results of `whereis node; echo path` :

```
[botManager@ip-f-o-o-o~]$ whereis node ; echo $PATH
```

`node:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/aws/bin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin:/opt/aws/bin`

Results of `df -h` :

```
[botManager@ip-f-o-o-o~]$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        484M   56K  484M   1% /dev
tmpfs           494M     0  494M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvda1      7.8G  1.2G  6.6G  15% /
```

Comment: after reboot what is the result of this command line : whereis node ; echo $PATH

Comment: Sorry for the slow answer, I have been delayed.
 `[botManager@ip~]$ whereis node; echo $PATH
node:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/aws/bin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin:/opt/aws/bin`
The result of `whereis node` is just `node:` without even a line return.

Comment: It seems your binaries was installed on an ephemeral drive. Are you using an EBS ? Reinstall everything, relaunched the previous command, then print the result of df -h

Comment: Yes, it is using EBS and the bloc is still attached since the creation of the instance. It's already a new instance since yesterday but I'll make a new one right-away and try again

Comment: If I had known that this afternoon was going to be that chaotic I would have asked this question tomorrow to answer faster, sorry and thank you at the same time.   I see no differences between before and after the reboot beside the result of `whereis node` so I checked manually the content of `/home/botManager/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/bin/` and the file `node` is still there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reboot, your $PATH is reset, `/home/botManager/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/bin` is no more present in, so your binary is unavailable.

Add this in your $PATH variable on startup : `/home/botManager/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/bin`

Edit

Add this to your .bashrc :

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/botManager/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/bin
```

Or Add this line to your /etc/environment file

```
/home/botManager/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/bin
```

Or create a symlink in /usr/bin

```
ln -s /home/botManager/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/bin/node /usr/bin/node
```

Comment: I first modified /etc/environment and made a typo. I'll just delete that server and do it again, it's not like I had done many things. Then I added it properly to the ~/.bashrc of botManager on the test server I created for this topic and it worked perfectly. Thank you very much.